# Configuration of bat file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

```
Cd /d "D:\Test"
START mvn clean install -DskipTests
xcopy /s "D:\Test\brsint-web\brsint-webapp\target\Test.war" "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0_1.2Latest (2)\webapps" /Y
Cd /d "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0_1.2Latest (2)\bin"
START startup.bat
```

I am trying to write a bat file which has series of actions I wanted to perform. I want to trigger 3rd line after 2nd line execution. 2nd line is a maven build which generates war file it takes time to complete. Mean while 3rd line i.e., copy command is getting executed before War file is generated. Please help me resolve.

Comment: Did you take a read of the information which comes up when you enter `Start /?` or `Help Start` in the Command prompt and see if there were any options worth trying? Oh and if the last line in your posted snippet is not the last line I would suggest perhaps using `Call` instead of `Start`, alternatively, use neither, just `startup.bat`.

Comment: thanks Call resolved my problem :)

Comment: I want to copy war file only if the maven build is success. But next line is getting triggered even on failure. Is there any way to check return code of maven build to stop execution if it is failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to maintain the structure you had as best as possible, I would suggest perhaps this:

```bat
CD /D "D:\Test"
(Call mvn clean install -DskipTests) || GoTo :EOF
XCopy "D:\Test\brsint-web\brsint-webapp\target\Test.war" "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0_1.2Latest (2)\webapps" /S /Y
CD "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0_1.2Latest (2)\bin"
Call "startup.bat"
```

*If the mvn command is not successful the script will end at that point!*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /Wait or /W flag after the Start Command.  This will spawn the process and wait for a Return or Exit code before continuing.

e.g.

```
Cd /d "D:\Test"
START /wait mvn clean install -DskipTests
xcopy /s "D:\Test\brsint-web\brsint-webapp\target\Test.war" "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0_1.2Latest (2)\webapps" /Y
Cd /d "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0_1.2Latest (2)\bin"
START /wait startup.bat
```

Comment: Had they read the help information on the `Start` command as I posted in a comment, they may also have noted the possibility of using the **`/D`** option, which may negate multiple `CD` commands!

Comment: I tried using /wait. Then, it never returns to the next line. I also looked into various options of start where I cant find a solution.

Comment: If I use /wait build process is done in new window but execution stops after building the war. Execution does not proceed even after completion of build in first window.